# How to modify app launcher bar for Guest account?

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, guest-session

How are changes made to the application launcher bar for the Guest account?

I installed Google Chrome, and I want the icon for it to appear on the launcher bar for the Guest account, and set Chrome as the default browser for the Guest account.

I can temporarily add Chrome to the app launcher bar as a guest, but it is removed after logoff.

(Edit: I'm a moderate level Linux user. I know my way around the command line, if that level of fiddling is necessary to make changes to the Guest account.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "Special purpose user" according to the guidance at the tuturial [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).